# Extract Statistics from CSV Data in Java with OpenCSV

Tags: java, string, parsing, csv, statistics

I am parsing a CSV file in Java with OpenCSV and would like to obtain (for example) the number of instances that the 3rd element of each line in the file states either "UDP" or "TCP." How can I select the specific data that I mentioned from where I am now and store it in a separate variable? (i.e. - an integer that shows a count of 20 if there are 20 instances of "UDP" throughout the file contained within the 3rd element of each line) So far, I am only able to print out the entire contents of the file which I am parsing as follows:

```
try {
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filePath), ',');

    // Reads the complete file into list of tokens.
    List<String[]> rowsAsTokens = null;
    try {
        rowsAsTokens = reader.readAll();
    } 
    catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Iterator<String[]> rowsAsTokensIt = rowsAsTokens.iterator();
    while (rowsAsTokensIt.hasNext()) {
        for (String token : rowsAsTokensIt.next()) {
            System.out.print(token + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to know how to get the nth element of an array?

Comment: Yes, I want to know how to get it and how to filter out specific data from it with an "IF" statement or whichever way is suitable to store that data in a separate variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is very, very basic Java or C or C++ and I would suggest you read something on Java.

```
double sum = 0;
for(String[] row: rowsAsTokens) {
    // check the first row is HELLO
    if(row[0].equals("HELLO")) {
        // get the second row as a double
        sum += Double.parseDouble(row[1]);
    }
}
// print the grand total once at the end
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: The output from this are the contents of row[1] for the number of instances where row[0] is true. I am instead looking for the sum total number for when the condition for for row[0].equals("HELLO") is met.

Comment: @THEDOCTOR I have changed.  Again this is really basic stuff.

Comment: Still not getting the right results. Based on your code, I get output for every instance where the row contains "HELLO" at row[0]. I am looking for one result with the grand total, not a running total. I am aware that this is basic stuff, you need not reiterate. I have not programmed for some time now and resolving something like this helps me on the path to proficiency. Thanks.

Comment: If you want one total at the end, I suggest you print the total once at the end. See my example. I have been programming for 27 years so I tend to take certain knowledge for granted. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would maintain the count in a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). I would also avoid using `readAll()` so you don't have to iterate over the data twice.

Just declare the map

```
Map<Object, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Then maintain a count for each value you encounter in the 3rd column

```
String [] row;
while ((row = reader.readNext()) != null) {
  String value = row[2]; // value in 3rd column

  // default count to 0 if not in map
  Integer count = countMap.get(value) != null ? countMap.get(value) : 0;

  // increment count in map
  countMap.put(value, count + 1);

}

System.out.println("UDP count: " + countMap.get("UDP"));
System.out.println("TCP count: " + countMap.get("TCP"));
```

As an alternative you could use [Super CSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/), which is highly flexible/configurable. The above solution is fine for a trivial scenario (such as keeping a count for 1 column), but if you keep adding more and more functionality it could easily become unreadable. Super CSV has a powerful [cell processor](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/cell_processors.html) API which automates conversions and constraints which can greatly simplify this.

For instance, you could write a [custom cell processor](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_new_cell_processor.html) that maintains a count for each unique column value it encounters.

```
package example;

import java.util.Map;

import org.supercsv.cellprocessor.CellProcessorAdaptor;
import org.supercsv.cellprocessor.ift.CellProcessor;
import org.supercsv.util.CsvContext;

public class Counter extends CellProcessorAdaptor {

  private final Map<Object, Integer> countMap;

  public Counter(final Map<Object, Integer> countMap) {
    super();
    if (countMap == null){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("countMap should not be null");
    }
    this.countMap = countMap;
  }

  public Counter(final Map<Object, Integer> countMap, final CellProcessor next) {
    super(next);
    if (countMap == null){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("countMap should not be null");
    }
    this.countMap = countMap;
  }

  @Override
  public Object execute(Object value, CsvContext context) {

    validateInputNotNull(value, context);

    // get count from map (default to 0 if doesn't exist)
    Integer count = countMap.get(value) != null ? countMap.get(value) : 0;

    countMap.put(value, count + 1);

    return next.execute(value, context);
  }

}
```

And then use the processor on the 3rd column

```
package example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.supercsv.cellprocessor.ParseDate;
import org.supercsv.cellprocessor.constraint.NotNull;
import org.supercsv.cellprocessor.ift.CellProcessor;
import org.supercsv.io.CsvListReader;
import org.supercsv.io.ICsvListReader;
import org.supercsv.prefs.CsvPreference;

public class Counting {

  private static final String CSV = "id,time,protocol\n" + "1,01:23,UDP\n"
      + "2,02:34,TCP\n" + "3,03:45,TCP\n" + "4,04:56,UDP\n"
      + "5,05:01,TCP";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    final Map<Object, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<Object, Integer>();

    final CellProcessor[] processors = new CellProcessor[] { 
        new NotNull(), // id
        new ParseDate("hh:mm"), // time
        new NotNull(new Counter(countMap)) // protocol
    };

    ICsvListReader listReader = null;
    try {
      listReader = new CsvListReader(new StringReader(CSV),
          CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

      listReader.getHeader(true);

      List<Object> row;
      while ((row = listReader.read(processors)) != null) {
        System.out.println(row);
      }

    } finally {
      listReader.close();
    }

    System.out.println("Protocol count = " + countMap);

  }

}
```

Output:

```
[1, Thu Jan 01 01:23:00 EST 1970, UDP]
[2, Thu Jan 01 02:34:00 EST 1970, TCP]
[3, Thu Jan 01 03:45:00 EST 1970, TCP]
[4, Thu Jan 01 04:56:00 EST 1970, UDP]
[5, Thu Jan 01 05:01:00 EST 1970, TCP]
Protocol count = {UDP=2, TCP=3}
```